# Manhua where the main character is unemployed and is then hired by a shady company to complete missions in another world

Tags: story-identification, manga

I believe this was a colored manhua. The main character starts off poor and with only his sister living on Earth and is unemployed. I believe the sister goes to school and is very pretty. Then suddenly he found a shady company to work with.

He completes his trial mission and achieves 100% that is never seen among the people. He can’t wait to go again when he receives his first paycheck.

In the story, he fights tough battles and achieves success to people who contracted with the shady company to offer their soul to achieve optimum success in the story because they were unsuccessful themselves and gave their soul to the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

**[*Dimensional mercenary*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/dimensional-mercenary)** (AKA *Ichawon Yongbyeong*)

> Would you like to find a job? Even at the cost of your soul? If so, then you’ve found the right place. Our job hunting advice website, Soul Sellers, is a site geared towards those willing to even sell their souls for employment; that’s right, people like you. Are you dealing with angels or demons?
>
> 30-year old freeloader Chul Ho Kang made a deal through this shady site, even selling his soul for the chance at what else? Money! An invitation to the other world for the weak and downtrodden of society for a chance to change their lot in life! That is the mission given to Chul Ho Kang!
>
> [image]